# How to render a component based on model parameter

Tags: ember.js

I have the requirement to render a template based on a property of my model.

My stratergy was to use custom if block helpers for the handle bars templates, something like this:

```
{{#ifequals type 'cars'}}
   {{cars-component}}
{{/ifequals}}
{{#ifequals type 'planes'}}
   {{planes-component}}
{{/ifequals}
```

but I cant create a block helper that resolves parameter passed by the template to the helper.

if I use  Handlebars.registerHandlebars, it resolves the variable name insted of the variable.

the reason i need to do this is because it is part of a plugin framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option blocks (special if statements) don't work properly in ember handlebars helpers.  https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2237

```
isCar: Ember.computed.equals('type', 'cars')
isPlane: Ember.computed.equals('type', 'planes')

{{#if isCar}}
   {{cars-component}}
{{/if}}
{{#if isPlan}}
   {{planes-component}}
{{/if}}
```

It almost looks like you can do it, but there is a problem with it, as is pointed out in the github issue above.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('iff', function(value,property, options) {
  if(value === property){
    return options.fn.apply(); 
  } else {
    return options.inverse.apply(); 
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhOWeWiJ/1/edit

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhOWeWiJ/2/edit

**You will get a bound blocks error when you try and implement something like this and the values actually change**

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2237

*Uncaught You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process*

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhOWeWiJ/3/edit
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UhOWeWiJ/3/edit

Comment: Well hell, I swore this didn't work, I don't remember anything happening that would show it worked, maybe it was with a property on a model instead of a model, but the example I just tried worked.

Comment: based on what wagenet's comments, its better to use computed properties.

Comment: Yeah, my original post was more correct, shoulda stuck with my gut.